# How do I remove an empty index from an array list?

Tags: java

User is suppose to enter 10 names into an array, the program will remove the 5th name from the list.

Here's some code I came up with:

```
String [] invites = new String [10];

//****User Input****         
System.out.println("Please enter 10 names: ");
System.out.println("*************************************************");

//****For loop****
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    invites[i] = sc.nextLine();
}

System.out.println("*************************************************");

//****Array size****
int Arraysize = 10;

//****Remove 5th Index****
int target = 4;//eliminate this element

for(int i = target; i < Arraysize -1; i++){
    invites[i] = invites[i+1];
}


//****reset last element****
invites[Arraysize - 1] = ("1");

//****Lower Logicalsize****
Arraysize --;

//****Display Array List****
for (String names : invites) {
     System.out.println(names);
}

System.out.println("*************************************************");
```

---

It will leave the 9th index a blank spaced when displayed to the user. I just want the blank space gone in the array list.

Comment: its not an array list, its just an array

Comment: You might want to zave a look at the length attribute of the array. And maybe an ArrayList<String> would be simpler to handle for you.

Comment: OT: You called your int `Arraysize`. This validates the java naming convention in two ways. 1.: variables should start with a lower case. 2.: use camelCase. So - please - name it `arraySize`

Comment: Does this have to be a `String[]` or can it actually be a `List<String>`? If it can, there is a `List.removeAll()` method you could use to remove the empty elements

Comment: why do you need the variable `Arraysize` anyways? You can call `invites.length` to get the array size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check the length of string before printing:

```
//****Display Array List****
for (String names : invites) {
    if(names != null && names.length() >= 1) //print names which have atleast one char
         System.out.println(names);
}
```

Comment: may be good to do a null check `if (names != null && names.length() >=1)`

Comment: Thanks Roushan and Lonely! that seemed to be the fix with that if statement under my for statement.

Comment: A more idiomatic way to write `names.length() >= 1` is `!names.isEmpty()`.

Comment: @AndyTurner - great suggestion

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood correctly, you want to display only those Strings of an array which is not empty. If this is the case we can check the value as if it's null or empty before giving sysout.

Answer (score 0):

You can perfectly use the `Arraysize` variable that you are already maintaining:

```
//****Display Array List****
for(int i = 0; i < Arraysize; i++) {
    System.out.println(invites[i]);
}
```